# Как задать значение dp программно?

Tags: java, android, density

Пытаюсь сделать вот так:

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int width_100dp = (int) (100 * scale + 0.5f);
    int high_100dp = (int) (100 * scale + 0.5f);
```

Но, при вызове выдает ошибку:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: У вас Context - null. Проблема точно не в том коде, коий вы показали.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Да уж, разобрался, спасибо. И что теперь с вопросом делать ?)

Comment: Закрывать как дубль)

Comment: Не, пусть будет просто закрыт как дубль.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб понял, думал просто что это я сделать должен.